# How to solve this error? in xcode

Tags: ios, swift, exc-bad-instruction

> warning: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var count = 0
    var label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Label
        var label = UILabel()
        label.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 150, width: 60, height: 60)
        label.text = "0"
        self.view.addSubview(label)

        //Button
        var button = UIButton()
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 250, width: 60, height: 60)
        button.setTitle("Click", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: .normal)
        self.view.addSubview(button)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.incrementCount), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func incrementCount() {
        self.count = self.count + 1
        self.label.text = "\(self.count)" //here got the warning
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `self.label` nil? You're not setting it in `viewDidLoad` because you are redeclaring `label` in there so it just creates another label rather than writing to the first one. Remove `var` from `var label = UILabel()` in `viewDidLoad` and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

A common cause of that error is attempting to force-unwrap a nil optional.

Your problem is trying to access `self.label` which is an implicitly unwrapped optional. It crashes because `self.label` is `nil`.

It is `nil` because in `viewDidLoad` you don't actually assign a value to your `label` property. Instead, you use a local variable of the same name.

Update your `viewDidLoad` to use the `label` property instead of a locale variable of the same name.

In other words, change:

```
var label = UILabel()
```

to:

```
label = UILabel()
```

Answer (score 0):

It should help. In your variable label was nil because you are creating new variable inside viewDidLoad

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var count = 0
    var label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Label
        label = UILabel()
        label.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 150, width: 60, height: 60)
        label.text = "0"
        self.view.addSubview(label)

        //Button
        var button = UIButton()
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 250, width: 60, height: 60)
        button.setTitle("Click", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: .normal)
        self.view.addSubview(button)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.incrementCount), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func incrementCount() {
        self.count = self.count + 1
        self.label.text = "\(self.count)" //here got the warning
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `viewDidLoad()` method, you are creating a new variable named "label". I think it's a mistake and you would like to set the class variable named "label" too.

To fix it, you only have to replace

```
//Label
var label = UILabel()
```

by

```
//Label
label = UILabel()
```

When you will try to access to the "label" variable in the `incrementCount` method, the variable will not be nil and your app will not crash.